# InternalServerError (500) using consuming REST services using WCF Rest Starter Kit

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, wcf-client

I recently downloaded the WCF Rest Starter Kit and attempted to connect to a REST service written in Java.

I can browse to the url of the service and the browser spits out xml.  However, I get a InternalServerError when attempting to connect via the HttpClient object.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
_uri = @"http://mytestservice";            
HttpClient http = new HttpClient(_uri);

http.TransportSettings.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

HttpResponseMessage response = http.Get();
response.EnsureStatusIsSuccessful();
```

Comment: Can you look in Fiddler to see what's the difference between the request which the browser sends and the request which is sent by the program? That should give you more information about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following to the default headers did the trick.

```
http.DefaultHeaders.Accept.Add("application/xml");
```